# How to keep indentation from previous line when building strings

Tags: c#, string

Consider the following example. I define a struct with a `ToString()` method

```
public struct InnerStruct
{
    public double a;
    public double b;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"InnerStruct:\n" +
               $"    a: {a}\n" +
               $"    b: {b}";
    }
}
```

Calling `ToString()`

```
 var i = new InnerStruct(){a=1, b=2};
 i.ToString()
 @"InnerStruct:
     a: 1
     b: 2
 "
```

So that `ToString()` gives a nice and readable string, where `a` and`b` is indented four spaces. However, lets say I have a new struct

```
public struct OuterStruct
{
    public double c;
    public InnerStruct inner;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"OuterStruct:\n" +
               $"    c: {c}\n" +
               $"    inner: {inner.ToString()}";
    }
}
```

now writing

```
var u = new OuterStruct(){c=3, inner=i};
u.ToString()
@"OuterStruct:
     c: 3
     inner: InnerStruct:
     a: 1
     b: 2
"
```

but thats not what I want. The newline `\n` forces the next line to start at the beginning and count four spacese from there. I want

```
@"OuterStruct:
     c: 3
     inner: InnerStruct:
         a: 1
         b: 2
"
```

I.e. I want the indentation of the members of the inner struct to start relative to the indentation of the inner struct. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an overload indicating a depth:

```
public override string ToString() 
{ 
    return ToString(0);
}

public string ToString(int depth)
{
    var spaces = new string(' ', 4 * depth);
    return $"InnerStruct:\n" +
           $"{spaces}    a: {a}\n" +
           $"{spaces}    b: {b}";
}
```

And then when printing this inner struct, pass the depth:

```
$"    inner: {inner.ToString(1)}";
```

Or pass `++depth` instead of `1`, whichever you want.

Comment: Note that if you intend to use it as `$"    inner: {inner.ToString(1)}";`, that you then should use `"InnerStruct:\n"` instead of `"{spaces}InnerStruct:\n"`.

Comment: Ha, beat me to it :)

Comment: Interesting :) would this work if i had even deeper nesting, inner-inner. Would I have to keep track of how deep the nesting is? I.e. pass 8, 12, 16 etc. depending on the depth.

Comment: @morty then you pass `++depth` to the next `ToString()` call.

Answer (score 1):

What about an override of ToString()?

```
public struct InnerStruct
{
    public double a;
    public double b;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToString(String.Empty);
    }

    public string ToString(string prefix )
    {
        return $"{prefix}InnerStruct:\n" +
               $"{prefix}    a: {a}\n" +
               $"{prefix}    b: {b}";
    }
}
```